# StackOverflow in continuation monad

Tags: f#, monads, computation-expression

Using the following continuation monad:

```
type ContinuationMonad() =
    member this.Bind (m, f) = fun c -> m (fun a -> f a c)
    member this.Return x = fun k -> k x

let cont = ContinuationMonad()
```

I fail to see why the following gives me a stack overflow:

```
let map f xs =
    let rec map xs =
        cont {
            match xs with
            | [] -> return []
            | x :: xs ->
                let! xs = map xs
                return f x :: xs
        }
    map xs id;;

let q = [1..100000] |> map ((+) 1)
```

While the following doesn't:

```
let map f xs =
    let rec map xs =
        cont {
            match xs with
            | [] -> return []
            | x :: xs ->
                let! v = fun g -> g(f x)
                let! xs = map xs
                return v :: xs
        }
    map xs id;;

let q = [1..100000] |> map ((+) 1)
```

Comment: Note that I am on VS 2012 RC, if anyone could test it has the same behavior on the current release of VS2010.

Comment: Yes, and it also has the same behavior in OCaml. See my answer below.

Comment: FWIW, this behavior can still be observed with VS2015, F# 4.0, Update 3 (though the answers indicate it cannot be blamed onto the compiler).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To fix your example, add this method to your definition of the monad:

```
member this.Delay(mk) = fun c -> mk () c
```

Apparently the part that overflows is the destruction of the large input list in the recursive call of `map`. Delaying it solves the problem.

Note that your second version puts the recursive call to `map` behind another `let!` which desugars to `Bind` and an extra lambda, in effect delaying the recursive call to `map`.

I had to pursue a few false trails before reaching this conclusion. What helped was observing that `StackOverflow` is thrown by `OCaml` as well (albeit at a higher `N`) unless the recursive call is delayed. While `F#` TCO has some quirks, `OCaml` is more proven, so this convinced me that the problem is indeed with the code and not the compiler:

```
let cReturn x = fun k -> k x
let cBind m f = fun c -> m (fun a -> f a c)

let map f xs =
  (* inner map loop overflows trying to pattern-match long lists *)
  let rec map xs =
    match xs with
      | [] -> cReturn []
      | x :: xs ->
        cBind (map xs) (fun xs -> cReturn (f x :: xs)) in
  map xs (fun x -> x)

let map_fixed f xs =
  (* works without overflowing by delaying the recursive call *)
  let rec map xs =
    match xs with
      | [] -> cReturn []
      | x :: xs ->
        cBind (fun c -> map xs c) (fun xs -> cReturn (f x :: xs)) in
  map xs (fun x -> x)

let map_fused f xs =
  (* manually fused version avoids the problem by tail-calling `map` *)
  let rec map xs k =
    match xs with
      | [] -> k []
      | x :: xs ->
        map xs (fun xs -> k (f x :: xs)) in
  map xs (fun x -> x)
```

Comment: You can solve this problem without adding the Delay member -- see my comment on John Palmer's response.

Comment: @JackP., I agree that adding the Delay member is not the only fix. However, you have to delay pattern-matching the input list so that it does not happen on entirely on the stack. If you do not do that, the code will overflow (if not at `N=100000` then at a higher `N`.

Answer (score 4):

The F# compiler is sometimes not very clever - in the first case it computes `map xs` then `f x` and then joins them, so `map xs` is not in a tail position.  In the second case, it can reorder the `map xs` to be in tail position easily.

Comment: I fail to see how `(f x)` can be computed anywhere but inside the continuation generated by the workflow.

Comment: @DavidGrenier -- John is correct. `(f x)` is computed inside the continuation generated by the workflow, but it is not computed inside it's *own* continuation. That is, the workflow only creates one continuation which wraps `(f x) :: xs` -- so when that continuation is called, it can't make a tail-call to `f`. When that continuation is executed, it has to push a stack frame every time it calls `f`, and since it's doing so recursively you're getting the `StackOverflowException`. In your second example, the F# compiler is able to generate tail-calls for everything.

Comment: @JackP I disagree with both the comment and your response. `map` returns immediately, tail-calling `map` is not relevant. `f` is not recursive, tail-calling `f` is not relevant either. Also, the fault is not with the F# compiler, OCaml does the same here, based on my tests.

Comment: I see now in what sense John's comment is correct. Having `map xs k`, rather than just `map xs`, in tail position is crucial. I just would phrase this differently, since F# compiler does not reorder code - this is all about how it is written.