# How does the Delay exactly works in continuation monad to prevent stackoverflow?

Tags: f#, workflow, stack-overflow, monads, continuation

This is a reference question to this: [StackOverflow in continuation monad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188779/stackoverflow-in-continuation-monad)
with whom I played a little and would need a few clarifications.

1) I suppose this:

```
member this.Delay(mk) = fun c -> mk () c
```

makes the behavior in computational workflow do the diffrence as showed by toyvo between these:

```
cBind (map xs) (fun xs -> cReturn (f x :: xs))  

cBind (fun c -> map xs c) (fun xs -> cReturn (f x :: xs))
```

So I don't exactly understand what is the trick, when
`(fun c -> map xs c)` is only different notation of `(map xs)`

2) Inference issue. - In OP's second map example I found out it doesn't compile due to inference problem with `v` value, because it infers `f` as `a -> b list`, instead of desired `a -> b`. Why it infers in this way? In case `let v = f x` it would infer well.

3) It seems to me that VS shows inaccurate type signatures in the tooltips: 
return type of the monad's Return is: `('e->'f)->f`, while the return type of the Bind is only `'c->'b`. -It seems it simplify `('e->'f)` to only `c` in the Bind case, or am I missing something here?

Thanks for the clarification,
tomas

**Edit - testing dump:**

```
let cReturn x = fun k -> k x
let cBind m f = 
    printfn "cBind %A" <| m id
    fun c -> m (fun a -> f a c)

let map_fixed f xs =
  let rec map xs =
    printfn "map %A" xs
    match xs with
      | [] -> cReturn []
      | x :: xs -> cBind (fun c -> map xs c) (fun xs -> cReturn (f x :: xs)) 
  map xs (fun x -> x)

let map f xs =
  let rec map xs =
    printfn "map %A" xs
    match xs with
      | [] -> cReturn []
      | x :: xs -> cBind (map xs) (fun xs -> cReturn (f x :: xs)) 
  map xs (fun x -> x)

[1..2] |> map_fixed ((+) 1) |> printfn "%A"
[1..2] |> map ((+) 1) |> printfn "%A"
```

map_fixed:
map [1; 2]
map [2]
map []
cBind []
map []
cBind [3]
map [2]
map []
cBind []
map []
[2; 3]

map:
map [1; 2]
map [2]
map []
cBind []
cBind [3]
[2; 3]

**Edit to question 2:**

```
let map f xs =
    let rec map xs =
        cont {
            match xs with
            | [] -> return []
            | x :: xs ->
                let v = f x // Inference ok
                //let! v = cont { return f x } // ! Inference issue - question 2
                let! xs = map xs
                return v :: xs
        }
    map xs id
```

Comment: Regarding your second question, inference seems to work just fine for me.

Comment: If I uncomment //let!.. it gives me: Type mismatch. Expecting a 'a but given a 'a list

Comment: I finaly see the mistake - was in my Bind definition - similar log as in point 1 - silly me, thanks for interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is exactly that `fun c -> map xs c` **is not** the same as `map xs`.  They have the same "meaning" in some sense, but their runtime semantics are different.  In the latter case, evaluating the expression results in an immediate call to the `map` function with `xs` as an argument (returning another function as the result).  On the other hand, evaluating `fun c -> map xs c` **does not** result in an immediate call to `map`!  The call to `map` is delayed until the resulting function is actually applied.  This is the critical difference that prevents a stack overflow.

Regarding your other questions, I can't quite make out what you're asking in your second question.  For your third question, the compiler has inferred the most general type possible for `Bind`.  You're right that the traditional type that you might expect is more specific than this, but it's not really a problem that you can call `Bind` in a wider set of contexts than is strictly necessary.  And if you really want a more specific type, you can always add annotations to constrain the signature.

Comment: With regard of my second question, you will see what is problem when you try to compile that second op's function - the type of the function parameter **f** is unexpected to me.

Comment: -"does not result in an immediate call to map" - but according to my test dump it does - before the cBind is evaluated - see my edit...

Comment: @tomasK - Your testing is flawed because you're applying `m` in your logging of `cbind`.  Change that line to just `printfn "cbind"` and you'll see that `map_fixed` really does delay calling `map`.